# Firebase shared authentication in polymer

Tags: javascript, firebase, polymer

I am currently building an application in polymer 1.7 with firebase integration. The integration also uses iron pages from the starter kit.

My question is to understand the best archtectual pattern available or adopted for best usage.

```
  index.html: <app></app>
    app.html: 
      <firebase-app>
      <firebase-auth>
      <firebase-document> (query)
      <firebase-document> (query)

      <iron-pages>
        <profile uid="[[user]]" data="[[data]]">
        <login uid="[[user]]">
        <contact>
        <latest data="[[data]]">
```

I have built in page switcher, which works fine but passing in the user bind every single time if i want to authenticate the page seems convoluted.

Furthermore, i want to separate it out so a query is run within the component, it gets all the information it requires. I am currently building a massive `app.html` and it doesnt seem write with web components principles.

Whats the recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<iron-meta>` component to share information across dom tree and `<iron-meta-query>` to get this data.

For instance, you can have iron-meta defined in your parent component

```
<iron-meta id="data" key="shared" value='{
     "id": "1"
   }'>
</iron-meta>
```

Then to get data in some of your children use

```
<iron-meta-query key="shared" value="{{sharedValue}}">
```

For more information about using `<iron-meta>` component see [Polymer documentation](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-meta)